# 'not to mention' and 'to say nothing of'

Tags: idiom-meaning

Can anyone please tell me whether they find the following 
uses of 'not to mention' and 'to say nothing of' natural?

1. John can do products, not to mention sums.
2. John can do sums, not to mention products.
3. John can do products, to say nothing of sums.
4. John can do sums, to say nothing of products.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Idiomatically, *not to mention* is more often used in ***negatory*** contexts *(John can't do sums, not to mention products)*. It's used in much the same way as ***A - let alone / never mind B***, in contexts where ***B*** is an even more "extreme" example than ***A***. So your first example is a bit unlikely, since most people would suppose *products (multiplication*) are more difficult than *sums (addition)*.

Comment: I don't find either of the *"to say nothing of"* examples natural, although I can't say why.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is your remark that 'B is an even more "extreme" example than A' restricted to the negative contexts? We could presumably say sentences like "John can write academic essays, not to mention a diary entry", couldn't we? In this example, 'to write academic essays', which stands for A in the pattern, is the more 'extreme', or difficult, activity than to write a diary entry.

Comment: As the two posted answers say, in assertions of the form *A, not to mention B*, element B is normally ***added for emphasis***. So ordinarily you'd expect B to be the more compelling example, which makes your *John can write academic essays, not to mention a diary entry* an unlikely / awkward utterance. It's much the same with ***to say nothing of***, as evidenced by this from Arnold Bennett: [*you would not even get as far as **print**, to say nothing of **library counters***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+say+nothing+of+library+counters%22).

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary entry:

> **not to mention**
>   Used to introduce an additional point which reinforces the point being made: *I’m amazed you find the time, not to mention the energy, to do any work at all*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/not-to-mention?q=not%20to%20mention)

The phrase *not to mention* is normally used to mention the items purportedly *not* mentioned, but as an aside rather than a primary statement. The 'secondary' items are (not) mentioned only as an aside ostensibly to play down their significance, but the intent is usually the opposite. The construct is a device that (paradoxically) understates the more impressive items to give them prominence. The phrase *to say nothing of* is used in a similar way.

In the dictionary entry, *time* is arguably less impressive than *energy* - time is there for the taking, but energy may not be.

In your examples, *sums* should come first if products are considered more impressive. However, **the sentences come across naturally only if it would *already* be impressive for John to be able to do sums**. If sums are standard fare, the construct is less able to make products impressive.

Answer (score 1):

"not to mention" is usually followed by more of the same, to emphasize how much there is: He has a mansion, not to mention a private plane and a yacht.

not to mention
B2 used when you ​want to ​emphasize something that you are ​adding to a ​list:
He's one of the ​kindest and most ​intelligent, not to mention ​handsome, men I ​know."

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-to-mention

Comment: This is correct:  a better example using the questioner's situation might be "John can do lots of maths problems:  products, division, subtraction, not to mention sums."

Comment: "not to mention" usually precedes the more impressive elements, so it would be appropriate to say: John can do lots of maths problems, including sums - not to mention subtraction, products and division.